# Disable and delete goa-daemon

Tags: 13.04, online-accounts

How to disable and delete goa-daemon. I'm not using online accounts and this daemon only consumes my memory and CPU.

Comment: If you will remove `goa-daemon` your system would become unstable. Removing it will remove all your accounts and packages like `empathy, evolution-data-server, gnome-control-center, gnome-online-accounts, indicator-datetime, indicator-power,` etc.. the list might so long depends upon the packages you have currently installed. So remove at your own risk.. Reply if you really want to remove it..

Comment: OK, then I don't want to remove it. If there is no way to disable it then I'll leave it. Thank you for reply

Comment: Hi, please read this article - disable goa demon is possible task, anyone who talking to you about removing dependencies just not recognize that this demon can be disabled.

Comment: @Svyatoslav You forgot to put link to your article

Comment: Oh, sorry - this link http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=839741

Comment: @Alen and this http://linuxg.net/how-to-display-the-hidden-startup-applications-on-ubuntu-13-04/

Comment: So user in linked thread reported this command worked for him: update-rc.d -f powernowd remove. Since goa-daemon has so may dependencies, will my system become unstable if I stop this daemon but without deleting it

Answer (score 5):

The "solution" isn't a solution at all, it's just the removal of powernow daemon, there are many daemons, the solution doesn't consist in removing any random daemon, but goa-daemon specifically. Which apparently doesn't get executed by the whole rc/sysv scheme.

I'm not sure yet how to disable it, but I saw some comment thanking someone for a tip on how to make hidden XDG-autostart applications (set through launcher files at /etc/xdg/autostart and ~/.config/autostart) appear on some Ubuntu GUI manager for default applications. Strangely enough, I didn't have goa-daemon on any xdg-autostart folder, but it was running still. I don't even have the powernow daemon.

I think it's autostarted by /usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.gnome.OnlineAccounts.service

It's not the right way to do it, but it probably can be disabled either removing the file or by editing the exec line and just adding an "echo" after "exec=". But there is probably a more proper way to manage "dbus-services".

Answer (score 5):

### 22.04 safe little hack

Simple and safe little hack, that can be easily reversed if needed. It just changes execute permissions for the daemon: (without removing anything that could unleash hell)

```
sudo chmod -x /usr/libexec/goa-daemon
```

Worked great for me in Ubuntu 22.04. Never saw him again, without any detected side-effects

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu Unity 22.10, w/o any negative side effects regarding the gnome-calendar which is connected to a google account.

Answer (score 0):

To disable the GOA service:

```
$ cd /usr/share/dbus-1/services
$ sudo ln -snf /dev/null  org.gnome.OnlineAccounts.service
$ sudo reboot now
```

Comment: Although I do not have a better solution, I don't think it is a good way to do it, because it is not revertable.

Comment: Commenting out the lines in `/usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.gnome.OnlineAccounts.service` appears to work.